# Floating text - When list items exceeds then item coming downside

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a birth day wishes bar on the top of the website. In div there is a ul. When I am adding more list items in `ul`. Then items coming downside. 
Please take a loot at [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDMJi.jpg).

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("getTodaysBirthday", "Home")',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    $("#ticker01").empty();
    $.each(data,
      function(index, optiondata) {
        $("#ticker01").append(optiondata.Txt);
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.news_sticker li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #eee;
  margin-right: 40px
}

.news_sticker {
  float: right;
  width: 85%;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px
}

.news_sticker li a:before {
  content: "";
  margin-right: 5px
}

.news_sticker li a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="latest_newsarea">
  <span>Birthday Wishes...</span>
  <ul id="ticker01" class="news_sticker">
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Simran !</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday M Vinoj  !</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Shiv Kumar!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Simran!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Dharmendra!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand !</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing jQuery, but also doesn't seem to recreate the problem when that's added....?

Comment: what is your problem actually? what you exactly want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `latest_newsarea` div is collapsing due to floating `ul` child inside it.

You need to clear the float to this collapsing issue solve this.

Here is how you can do it.

```
   .latest_newsarea:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
```

```css
.news_sticker li a{display:inline-block; color:#eee; margin-right:40px}
.news_sticker{float:right; width:85%; padding:5px 15px 5px 5px}
.news_sticker li a:before{content:""; margin-right:5px}
.news_sticker li a:before{display:inline-block; font-family:FontAwesome; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:1}

.latest_newsarea:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.latest_newsarea {
  background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<div class="latest_newsarea">
<span>Birthday Wishes...</span>
<ul id="ticker01" class="news_sticker" >
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Simran !</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday M Vinoj  !</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Shiv Kumar!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Simran!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Dharmendra!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Happy Birthday Lalchand !</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if this solves your collapsing parent problem.

Here is a link with some methods of clearing floats: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Thanks.

Comment: I have added this code in CSS but problem not resolved.

Comment: let me make a fiddle for this.

Comment: @satputenandkumar I've added the fiddle in this you can see that without my code the background color doesn't apply to the full div but with it color the whole div. 

If this doesn't solve your problem that you might have added fixed height somewhere in your code.